How to get correct index in proxy model if sourceModel() is also proxy model?
I have two proxy models that filter columns of my main model. This one also filter rows
LayersProxyModel::LayersProxyModel(QObject* parent) : QSortFilterProxyModel(parent)
{
       
}


bool LayersProxyModel::filterAcceptsColumn(int source_column, 
                                           const QModelIndex &source_parent) const
{
    switch (static_cast<DataBaseModel::Columns>(source_column))
    {
        case DataBaseModel::Columns::LayerName:
            return true;
        default:
            return false;
    }
    return false;
}

bool LayersProxyModel::lessThan(const QModelIndex &left, 
                                const QModelIndex &right) const
{
    int filterColumn = static_cast<int>(DataBaseModel::Columns::LayerName);

    QVariant leftData = sourceModel()->data(left, filterColumn);
    QVariant rightData = sourceModel()->data(right, filterColumn);
    
    // QVariant < QVariant Q_DEPRECATED
    return leftData.toString() < rightData.toString();
}

bool LayersProxyModel::filterAcceptsRow(int source_row, const QModelIndex &source_parent) const
{
    int filterColumn = static_cast<int>(DataBaseModel::Columns::LayerName);
    
    QModelIndex index = sourceModel()->index(source_row, filterColumn, source_parent);
    QVariant data = sourceModel()->data(index);
    for (int row = 0; row < source_row; ++row)
    {
        QModelIndex previousIndex = sourceModel()->index(row, filterColumn, source_parent);
        if (sourceModel()->data(previousIndex) == data)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

This one filter only columns
PacketLayerPurposeProxyModel::PacketLayerPurposeProxyModel(QObject* parent) : 
QSortFilterProxyModel(parent)
{
       
}

bool PacketLayerPurposeProxyModel::filterAcceptsColumn(int source_column, 
                                                       const QModelIndex &source_parent) const
{
  
    switch (static_cast<DataBaseModel::Columns>(source_column))
    {
        case DataBaseModel::Columns::PacketName:
        case DataBaseModel::Columns::LayerName:
        case DataBaseModel::Columns::PurposeName:
        case DataBaseModel::Columns::Manipulators:
            return true;

        default:
            return false;
    }
    return false;
}

What I would like to do:
auto p_l_p_dbmodel = new PacketLayerPurposeProxyModel(p_l_p_tableView);
p_l_p_tableView->setSourceModel(main_model);

LayersProxyModel *layers_proxy_model = new LayersProxyModel(this);
layers_proxy_model->setSourceModel(p_l_p_dbmodel);

The problem is that when the sourceModel is a proxy model, the index of the column by which I filter is in a different position and I don’t understand how I can translate the index of the source model into the index of the proxy model
bool LayersProxyModel::filterAcceptsRow(int source_row, const QModelIndex &source_parent) const
{
    int filterColumn = static_cast<int>(DataBaseModel::Columns::LayerName);

***PROBLEM IS HERE
    filterСolumn == 6 but in the proxy model the index of this column is 2 and calling 
    this function returns invalid indexes and the data is not displayed when sourceModel() 
    is a proxy model***

    QModelIndex index = sourceModel()->index(source_row, filterColumn, source_parent);
    QVariant data = sourceModel()->data(index);
    for (int row = 0; row < source_row; ++row)
    {
        QModelIndex previousIndex = sourceModel()->index(row, filterColumn, source_parent);
        if (sourceModel()->data(previousIndex) == data)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

Just I have several views and I need to adapt this function to work with both, when source model is a proxy model and when source model is actual model

Can't you just check if the source is a proxy model and call its mapToSource() to get the actual column?

@musicamante I can, but I don't understand, how to get index to call mapToSource().
`
int filterColumn = static_cast(DataBaseModel::Columns::LayerName);
const QAbstractProxyModel* proxyModel = qobject_cast<const QAbstractProxyModel*>(sourceModel());

if(proxyModel)
{
    QModelIndex index = proxyModel->mapToSource( how to get actual index here )

}

`

Actually, mapToSource() is probably unnecessary: since the row count of the p_l_p_tableView proxy doesn't change, it means that the source_row in filterAcceptsRow() will be the same. Therefore, if the source is a proxy, just access its own sourceModel()->index() with the known filterColumn.

@АндрейПетров Any comment on my answer?

Remember that the corresponding getter/setter methods of QAbstractProxyModel are declared with QAbstractItemModel *:
QAbstractItemModel *QAbstractProxyModel::sourceModel() const
void QAbstractProxyModel::setSourceModel(QAbstractItemModel *sourceModel)

In that regard, proxy models work like views. They do not use, know nor need to know the actual type of their source. All they need is the methods defined in QAbstractItemModel.
The next part of your question is about how a proxy model does the translation between an index owned by it and the corresponding index in its source. This is done with the 2 methods:
virtual QModelIndex mapFromSource(const QModelIndex &sourceIndex) const
virtual QModelIndex mapToSource(const QModelIndex &proxyIndex) const

These 2 methods are pure virtual in QAbstractProxyModel but they have an implementation in QSortFilterProxyModel: they use the protected methods filterAcceptsRow, filterAcceptsColumn and a few others to do the mapping.
Implementation details are not important. All you need to consider is: there are 2 methods, mapFromSource and mapToSource that translate indexes "somehow".

With that knowledge, let us see what happens when a view calls model()->data(someIndex, someRole):

The view's model (model1) reads someIndex to determine what it must return.To the view, model1 is a black box; everything that happens here is up to it.If model1 is a proxy model and it determines it needs data from its source to return a result, then data(someIndex, someRole) is translated into something like:
QAbstractItemModel* model2 = sourceModel();
QModelIndex sourceIndex = mapToSource(someIndex);
return model2->data(sourceIndex, someRole);

Let us call the transformation from someIndex to sourceIndex t1; now and follow the call.

Now, model2 reads sourceIndex to know what it must return.Just like model1 was a black box to the view, model2 is a black box to model1; whatever needs to be done is up to model2.If model2 is a proxy model, it will apply a transformation (t2) on the passed index before calling data on its source model, called model3.

... and the same logic is applied repeatedly until reaching modeln that is not a proxy model and can return data directly.


Seen from afar, someIndex was transformed into tn(tn-1(...(t3(t2(t1(someIndex))))...)) but each successive proxy model applied a single transformation without the knowledge of the model (or view) above it.

For illustration, here is an example of a proxy model class. The class makes a rotation of columns, by moving them 1 unit to the left. To allow for rotations of more than 1 column, several instances are stacked one after the other (obviously, in production code, you would allow the proxy model to rotate columns by more than 1 unit to achieve the same result; this is for illustration only).
As I explained above, instances of this class are oblivious what their source is.
#include <QApplication>
#include <QtGui/QStandardItemModel>
#include <QtCore/QIdentityProxyModel>
#include <QtWidgets/QTableView>
class ColumnRotationProxyModel : public QAbstractProxyModel {
public:
    ColumnRotationProxyModel() {}
    QModelIndex index(int row, int column, const QModelIndex& parent = QModelIndex()) const override
    {
        if (parent.isValid())
            return QModelIndex();
        return createIndex(row, column, sourceModel()->index(row, column).internalPointer());
    }
    QModelIndex parent(const QModelIndex&) const override
    {
        return QModelIndex();
    }
    int rowCount(const QModelIndex& parent = QModelIndex()) const override
    {
        if (parent.isValid())
            return 0;
        return sourceModel()->rowCount();
    }
    int columnCount(const QModelIndex& parent = QModelIndex()) const override
    {
        if (parent.isValid())
            return 0;
        return sourceModel()->columnCount();
    }
    QModelIndex mapToSource(const QModelIndex& proxyIndex) const override
    {
        if (!proxyIndex.isValid())
            return QModelIndex();
        int colCount = columnCount(),
             column = (proxyIndex.column() + 1) % colCount;
        return sourceModel()->index(proxyIndex.row(), column);
    }
    QModelIndex mapFromSource(const QModelIndex& sourceIndex) const override
    {
        if (!sourceIndex.isValid())
            return QModelIndex();
        int colCount = sourceModel()->columnCount(),
            column = (sourceIndex.column() + colCount - 1) % colCount;
        return index(sourceIndex.row(), column);
    }
};


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QStandardItemModel model;
    for (int r = 0; r < 2; ++r) {
        QList<QStandardItem*> row;
        for (int c = 0; c < 5; ++c)
            row.push_back(new QStandardItem(QString("item %1,%2").arg(r+1).arg(c+1)));
        model.appendRow(row);
    }


    ColumnRotationProxyModel rotModel1, rotModel2, rotModel3;
    rotModel1.setSourceModel(&model);
    rotModel2.setSourceModel(&rotModel1);
    rotModel3.setSourceModel(&rotModel2);

    QTableView v0, v1, v2, v3;
    v0.setWindowTitle("Original");
    v1.setWindowTitle("Rotation1");
    v2.setWindowTitle("Rotation2");
    v3.setWindowTitle("Rotation3");

    v0.setModel(&model);
    v1.setModel(&rotModel1);
    v2.setModel(&rotModel2);
    v3.setModel(&rotModel3);

    v0.show();
    v1.show();
    v2.show();
    v3.show();
    return app.exec();
}


To go further:
In the rare cases where the existing subclasses of QAbstractProxyModel are insufficient for you, note that overriding mapToSource and mapFromSource is tricky.Qt makes it easy to get them wrong, be careful...
Below is a simplified version of the above code, using QIdentityProxyModel so that fewer methods need to be implemented. Importantly, it uses (almost) the same code for mapToSource and mapFromSource as above, yet the result is very different and buggy (columns are not neatly rotated).
You should get no warning during compilation / execution but hopefully can find the bug easily: from my experience, misbehaving models ALWAYS cause mouse selection issues in QTableViews or QTreeViews. That is very much the case with the code below.
#include <QApplication>
#include <QtGui/QStandardItemModel>
#include <QtCore/QIdentityProxyModel>
#include <QtWidgets/QTableView>
class ColumnRotationProxyModel : public QIdentityProxyModel {
public:
    ColumnRotationProxyModel() {}
    QModelIndex mapToSource(const QModelIndex& proxyIndex) const override
    {
        if (!proxyIndex.isValid())
            return QModelIndex();
        int colCount = columnCount(),
             column = (proxyIndex.column() + 1) % colCount;
        return sourceModel()->index(proxyIndex.row(), column);
    }
    QModelIndex mapFromSource(const QModelIndex& sourceIndex) const override
    {
        if (!sourceIndex.isValid())
            return QModelIndex();
        int colCount = sourceModel()->columnCount(),
            column = (sourceIndex.column() + colCount - 1) % colCount;
        return QIdentityProxyModel::mapFromSource(sourceIndex.siblingAtColumn(column));
    }
};


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QStandardItemModel model;
    for (int r = 0; r < 2; ++r) {
        QList<QStandardItem*> row;
        for (int c = 0; c < 5; ++c)
            row.push_back(new QStandardItem(QString("item %1,%2").arg(r+1).arg(c+1)));
        model.appendRow(row);
    }


    ColumnRotationProxyModel rotModel1, rotModel2, rotModel3;
    rotModel1.setSourceModel(&model);
    rotModel2.setSourceModel(&rotModel1);
    rotModel3.setSourceModel(&rotModel2);

    QTableView v0, v1, v2, v3;
    v0.setWindowTitle("Original");
    v1.setWindowTitle("Rotation1");
    v2.setWindowTitle("Rotation2");
    v3.setWindowTitle("Rotation3");

    v0.setModel(&model);
    v1.setModel(&rotModel1);
    v2.setModel(&rotModel2);
    v3.setModel(&rotModel3);

    v0.show();
    v1.show();
    v2.show();
    v3.show();
    return app.exec();
}

